# How do you set a link for photos uploaded to your application album on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

With the graph API you can upload to an album specific to your application if you have publish_actions/publish_stream.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

What I want to know is how to create a link back to the original content, like in photos uploaded by Instagram, as shown here;

[image: like this]

Is this a special integration with Instagram since they are owned by FB, or is it just an undocumented parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Instagram's photo uploads are using the Open Graph APIs here, they're using action with an attached photo which links back to their site, I'm unsure if the 'View on Inastagram' link specifically is publicly available, but photo uploads that link back to the photo inside your own app are possible for any app, and are documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/adding-photos-to-stories/)